# Audio assets in Rails brings No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use an audio file in rails. I created a folder `audios` under `app\assets\`. I would like to use the assets precompile so that I don't have to put the file under `app\public`

Right now I'm getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/audios/audio_file.wav")
```

If I change the url from `URL/audios/audio_file.wav` to `URL/assets/audio_file.wav` it works. How can I fix the problem? What is the right way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, in case you didn't realize it already: your new `app/assets/audios` folder is already in the load path... you just need to restart your server for Sprockets to pick it up.

In **development**, assets are available at the relative url: `/assets/<asset file name>`.

For example, assuming your wav file is located at `/app/assets/audios/audio_file.wav` in the filesystem, it would be accessible at the relative url `/assets/audio_file.wav` in the browser. This is because Sprockets/Dev-Rails knows to search the `/app/assets` folder and its subdirectories when locating assets.

In **production**, assets precompilation (typically) happens on deploy. At this time, your wav file is copied to e.g. `/public/assets/audio_file-<MD5 fingerprint>.wav` and is accessible at the relative url: `/assets/audio_file-<MD5 fingerprint>.wav`.

Because of the different naming styles used between development and production, any time you want to refer to an asset you should do so using a helper method (even in CSS!). That is, production includes the MD5 fingerprint, whereas development does not. But you don't have to worry about any of that so long as you use a helper:

- For images: `<%= image_tag('homes/logo.png') %>` -- given an image file that lives in `/app/assets/images/homes/logo.png` on the file system.
- For non-standard assets, such as audio files: `<%= asset_path('audio_file.wav') %>`, which would produce a relative path of `/assets/audio_file.wav`.