# Add sound when click on image with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm trying to add a beep sound when clicking on an image (or a button) on my website. I tried with two different ways to do it, but none is working. I am using Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.6.3.

So my mp3 audio is in `my-project-name/app/assets/audios/sound.mp3`

In `my-project-name/config/application.rb` i have the following code :

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.load_defaults 5.2
  config.assets.precompile << "audios/*"
end
```

In `my-project-name/app/views/pages/home.html.erb` i have this code for my first attempt :

```
<!-- First attempt -->
<a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">
   <%= image_tag('mypicture.jpg') %>
</a>

<script>
  var bleep = new Audio();
  bleep.src = "../../assets/audios/sound.mp3";
</script>
```

And i have this code for my second attempt (still in in `my-project-name/app/views/pages/home.html.erb`) :

```
<!-- Second attempt -->
<button id="clickme" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
   Click me!
</button>

<script>    
   const boutton = document.querySelector("#clickme");
   boutton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      boutton.classList.toggle("disabled");
      boutton.innerText = "Bingo!";
      const audio = new Audio('/app/assets/audios/sound.mp3');
      audio.play();
   });
</script>
```

I also tried with [audio_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/audio_tag) but didn't figured out. Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using inline script tags you can create a delegated event handler that will work properly with Turbolinks.

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/beeper.js
const audio = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=mp3');
document.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  let el = event.target;
  if (el.matches('.beeper')) {
    console.log("beep!");
    audio.play();
    el.classList.toggle("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="beeper">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working! But mine is not, i think there is a problem with my relative path ? I have : `const audio = new Audio('../../assets/audios/sound.mp3')`

Comment: Yeah, you want to change the extension of the file to `.js.erb` and use the assets path helpers to link to the file. `new Audio("<%= asset_path('audios/sound.mp3') %>")` instead of hard-coding it. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb

Comment: Thx for your fast answer! Now i have an error : "The asset "audios/sound.mp3" is not present in the asset pipeline.". I tried `rake tmp:clear` and `rake assets:precompile` but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried restarting? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552799/544825

Comment: You should'nt have to be doing any precompilation in development though. Does this apply to other folders in `assets` as well? Like if you for the sake of debbuging put the file in `/assets` or `/assets/images`?

Comment: Ok i succeeded! I had to use this path : `<%= asset_path('sound.mp3') %>`
Now this is working if i click once, but what if i want to click several times (and play the sound several times) on the button ?

Comment: Just remove `el.classList.toggle("disabled");` or change the selector to `el.matches('.beeper')`. I though you where only looking to play it once from your code.

Comment: Thank you so much :)