# Can't play .wav file in Rails web app: RoutingError/404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, routes, asset-pipeline, wav

I'm trying to play a WAV file from my assets folder but I keep getting errors. The audio tag looks like this:

```
<audio src="<%= asset_path('/audios/opening.wav') %>">
Browser not compatible
</audio>
```

And I use a Javascript function to play it with `.play()`. When I test the function with a full path for WAV files that are actually hosted on the web, it works fine. It's just the one in my assets that's failing.

**WAV Path**:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── audios
│   │   │   └── opening.wav
```

**Browser console error**:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/audios/opening.wav net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

**Server error**:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/audios/opening.wav"):
```

I'm positive that there must be a better way than creating routes for each individual audio asset, but I haven't found any solutions on here that have worked. I've seen similar questions about this using `audio_path` but it seems that method may have been deprecated. Appreciate any advice I can get!

- Rails 7.0.3.1
- ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin20]

Comment: did you restart the server? does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552038/audio-assets-in-rails-brings-no-route-matches

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I have restarted the sever. I did that a few times throughout testing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using `audio_path` instead of `asset_path` was the way to go! It wasn't working at first but worked after I added `//= link_tree ../audios` to the `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file.